# XML to Database in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

Using VB.NET, how do I add the values from an XML file into an SQL Server database with a similar schema?

Comment: I'd recommend reading the FAQ and then rewording your question. It's quite poorly written. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an XSL Transform to create an insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the methods off the top of my head but you ought to be able to load the file into a DataTable and then use ADO.net to get it into the database (look into the SqlBulkCopy class if you're using a SQL Server DB).

This ought to get you enough words to punch into  and find a good example.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is using the DataSet class's ReadXml() method. Then, as the user above mentions, the dataset contains one (1) DataTable. It's pretty easy to get that into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

can't use xsl transform, you need a string for query, not another xml